How to add columns to a Pandas DataFrame containing max of each row, AND corresponding column name using iloc or iloc?
This is a revisit to the question Add columns to pandas dataframe containing max of each row, AND corresponding column name where a solution was provided using the now deprecated method ix. How can you do the same thing using iloc or loc instead? I've tried both, but I'm getting:

IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 3 but corresponding boolean dimension is 5

Here's a sample DataFrame:
   a  b  c  maxval
0  1  0  0       1
1  0  0  0       0
2  0  1  0       1
3  1  0  0       1
4  3  1  0       3

And here's the desired output:
    a  b  c  maxval maxcol
0   1  0  0  1      a
1   0  0  0  0      a,b,c
2   0  1  0  1      b
3   1  0  0  1      a
4   3  1  0  3      a


Here ix is used to select the columns up to c, you can do the same with loc:
df['maxcol'] = (df.loc[:, :'c'].eq(df['maxval'], axis=0)
                  .apply(lambda x: ','.join(df.columns[:3][x==x.max()]),axis=1)
               )

Or, since [:3] is used later with iloc:
df['maxcol'] = (df.iloc[:, :3].eq(df['maxval'], axis=0)
                  .apply(lambda x: ','.join(df.columns[:3][x==x.max()]),axis=1)
               )

A variant with a dot product:
tmp = df.loc[:, :'c']
df['maxcol'] = (tmp.eq(df['maxval'], axis=0)
                @ (tmp.columns+',')).str[:-1]

Or melt+groupby.agg:
df['maxcol'] = (df
   .melt('maxval', ignore_index=False)
   .query('maxval == value')
   .groupby(level=0)['variable'].agg(','.join)
)

Output:
   a  b  c  maxval maxcol
0  1  0  0       1      a
1  0  0  0       0  a,b,c
2  0  1  0       1      b
3  1  0  0       1      a
4  3  1  0       3      a


@mozway Is the line tmp = df.loc[:, :'c'] included to make things easier to read? Or does it have to be isolated?

@vestland it's to be able to select the columns only once, since in your original example you have the extra maxval column. If you want a one-liner you'd have to slice twice: df['maxcol'] = df.iloc[:, :3].eq(df['maxval'], axis=0).dot(df.columns[:3]+',').str[:-1]

If you don't need the commas, you can use:
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'a': [1, 0, 0, 1, 3],
  'b': [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
  'c': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
})

df.eq(df.max(axis=1), axis=0).mul(df.columns).sum(axis=1)
# returns:
0      a
1    abc
2      b
3      a
4      a

If you need the commas, you can use the .agg method:
maxcol = (
   df.eq(df.max(axis=1), axis=0)
     .mul(df.columns)
     .agg(lambda r: ','.join(filter(bool, r), axis=1)
)
df['maxcol'] = maxcol


Thank you, James! I would sure like those commas, though. Any suggestions on how to elegantly implement that with your suggested solution?

@vestland you can add the comma, compute the mul/sum then remove the trailing comma. This is almost what I did in my variant but using a dot product ;)

Here this would be df.eq(df.max(axis=1), axis=0).mul(df.columns+',').sum(axis=1).str[:-1] ; with a dot product: df.eq(df.max(axis=1), axis=0).dot(df.columns+',').str[:-1]

Updated to include the comma separator.

This is also done by like this
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'a': [1, 0, 0, 1, 3],
    'b': [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    'c': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    'maxval': [1, 0, 1, 1, 3]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def find_max_cols(row):
    max_cols = row[:-1] == row['maxval']
    if row['maxval'] == 0:
        return ','.join(max_cols.index[max_cols])
    else:
        return ','.join(max_cols.index[max_cols])

df['maxcol'] = df.apply(find_max_cols, axis=1)

print(df)

which gives you expected output
   a  b  c  maxval maxcol
0  1  0  0       1      a
1  0  0  0       0  a,b,c
2  0  1  0       1      b
3  1  0  0       1      a
4  3  1  0       3      a



Given:
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'a': [1, 0, 0, 1, 3],
    'b': [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    'c': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    'maxval': [1, 0, 1, 1, 3]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

You can use:
r, c = np.where(df_i.eq((m:=df_i.max(1)) , axis=0))
df['maxval'] = m
df['maxcol'] = df_i.columns[c].to_series().groupby(r).agg(','.join)
df

Output:
   a  b  c  maxval maxcol
0  1  0  0       1      a
1  0  0  0       0  a,b,c
2  0  1  0       1      b
3  1  0  0       1      a
4  3  1  0       3      a

